# Single column (with spaces) name gets split into two

Tags: mysql

I am using codeigniter `insert_batch($table, $data);`
I have a column name as "Comment posted by the customer".

When I try to batch insert data into it. The insert query changes as:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `Name`, `Status`,`Comment posted by the` `customer`, `isActive`) VALUES (),(),()...;
```

As seen the column splits up into 2 parts - 
1.Comment posted by the
2.customer

And this throws an error. How do I overcome this? I need to insert it considering it as a single column.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against spaces in column names as you will always have problems with it. Use underscores or camelCase instead.

Comment: i would strongly advice against using camelCase  @Scorpioo590 as some os are case sensitive when you mistype.. using underscores and lowercase  as `comment_posted_by_the` is a better convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the query like this

```
INSERT INTO table (id, Name, Status, `Comment posted by the customer`, isActive) VALUES (),(),()
```

**UPDATE**

You can omit the column names and specify the values for all columns

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (), (), ()
```

Comment: Yes, I have added backtick to all the fields, but it still then shows. Please check again I have edited my post.

Comment: how about using brackets (although it is a long shot) : INSERT INTO table (id, Name, Status, [Comment posted by the customer], isActive) VALUES (),(),()

Comment: Okay, I can try this but how do I add brackets to column names in code igniter batch insert.

Comment: *"Okay, I can try this but how do I add brackets to column names in code igniter batch insert. "* @gauri you don't as brackets are SQL Server (MSSQL) valid syntax not MySQL's it will give a parse error..